Micro Glitch during screen rotation with composables and camerax viewfinder with config overridden
I would like to have my camera rotate smoothly avoiding configurato changes, but leaving the rotation unlocked.
I have seen in the Samsung camera App that it is possible,as the ui and the System bar update their Position with the rotation, but the viewfinder's preview rotate smoothly.
I then set in the manifest configChanges to all possible vales (I will remove those unnecessary one by one once finished).
The onCreate is not called on rotation, but the view are recomposed.
In the manifest I set android:rotationAnimation="seamless".
Even leaving only the AndroidView there is this very short step in the rotation.
I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, I am not an expert, probably I am doing some basic error..
This is my code:
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
/*                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {*/
                    AndroidView(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        factory = { ctx ->  PreviewView(ctx).let {  takePicAVM.preview.setSurfaceProvider(it.surfaceProvider) ; it }},
                    )
                    CameraScreen()
//                }
            }
        }

In onAttachedToWindow:
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }

I tried also compiling with Release instead of debug, but the Performance was almost the same.
